# Possible weed identification

Tags: identification, weeds

Good evening,

This spring/summer, a plant emerged, and I'm not sure if it's a weed or not.

It's grown about 3ft this year, and there are a few of the same plant within a radius of about a metre.

If it's a weed with rhizomes, I'll need to get rid of it this autumn, but I didn't want to get rid of it if it's a tree - we recently cleared a lot of holly, so all sorts has sprouted this year.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What's your location (just in general, not specifically)?

Comment: Hi Jurp, I'm near Guildford, Surrey (UK)

Comment: Any shrubs or trees with similar foliage in the vicinity?

Comment: Check near leaves, in the stalk, if there are one or two glandes.

Comment: No shrubs or trees with similar leaves in the vicinity, which seems strange to me, as it must have seeded from somewhere. I will check for glandes - thank you

Comment: I checked today, @Giacomo, and there were no visible glandes

Comment: The new photo seems a different plant. This remember me something (but I cannot remember exactly what, or the name: the long yearly branches much more reddish then the old one). Could you add a photo of bottom of leaves, and one with the buds?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does seem a different plant :-) but it's the same plant a few weeks later. Sure, I will add the photos - thank you